# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes everytime I run the command 'make qemu'. How can I solve it?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, qemu, xv6

I searched this solution on the internet but couldn't find much. I am doing my Operating System assignment on XV6. I am using the shell file below every time I need to emulate on qemu.

```
make clean
make
make qemu
```

Qemu emulator runs and asks for command. Then it freezes suddenly and makes whole screen shadowy. Mouse pointer disappears and I can't close any window. I can't figure out what's wrong with it as I am new to it. Any solution or link would be helpful. Thank you.